# How do i convert one column from an imported csv using numpy from string to float?

Tags: python, numpy, genfromtxt

I have two csv files which i have imported to python using numpy.
the data has 2 columns:

```
[['month' 'total_rainfall']        
 ['1982-01' '107.1']    
 ['1982-02' '27.8']    
 ['1982-03' '160.8']    
 ['1982-04' '157']    
 ['1982-05' '102.2']
```

I need to create a 2D array and calculate statistics with the 'total_rainfall' column. (Mean,Std Dev, Min and Max)

So i have this:

```
import numpy as np    
datafile=np.genfromtxt("C:\rainfall-monthly-total.csv",delimiter=",",dtype=None,encoding=None)    
print(datafile)    
rainfall=np.asarray(datafile).astype(np.float32)    
print (np.mean(datafile,axis=1))
```

> ValueError: could not convert string to float: '2019-04'

Comment: You need to specify `names=True`.   Then look at the array.  It should have  2 fields, with the 2nd being numbers.

Answer (score 1):

Converting str to float is like below:

```
>>> a = "545.2222"
>>> float(a)
545.22220000000004
>>> int(float(a))
545
```

**but** the error message says the problem is converting `2019-04` to float.

when you want to convert `2019-04` to float it doesn't work because float numbers don't have `-` in between . That is why you got error.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert values of rainfall into `float` or `int` but date can't be converted. To convert date into `int` you have to split the string and combine it back as date formate then convert it to milliseconds as:

```
from datetime import datetime

month1 = '1982-01' 
date = datetime(month1.split('-')[0], month1.split('-')[1], 1)
milliseconds = int(round(date.timestamp() * 1000))
```

This way, you assume its first date of the month.

Answer (score 0):

Your error message reads *could not convert string to float*,
but actually your problem is a bit different.

Your array contains **string** columns, which should be converted:

- *month* - to *Period* (month),
- *total_rainfall* - to *float*.

Unfortunately, *Numpy* has been created to process arrays where all
cells are of **the same** type, so much more convenient tool is *Pandas*,
where each column can be of its **own** type.

First, convert your *Numpy* array (I assume *arr*) to a *pandasonic*
DataFrame:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(arr[1:], columns=arr[0])
```

I took column names from the initial row and data from
following rows. Print *df* to see the result.

So far both columns are still of *object* type (actually *string*),
so the only thing to do is to convert both columns,
each to its desired type:

```
df.month = pd.PeriodIndex(df.month, freq='M')
df.total_rainfall = df.total_rainfall.astype(float)
```

Now, when you run `df.info()`, you will see that both
columns are of proper types.

To process your data, use also *Pandas*. It is a more convenient tool.

E.g. to get quarterly sums, you can run:

```
df.set_index('month').resample('Q').sum()
```

getting (for your data sample):

```
        total_rainfall
month                 
1982Q1           295.7
1982Q2           259.2
```